# Intellij warning: Return value of the method is never used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, return-value

I have some code that seems OK, but Intellij IDEA warns about many of its methods that `return` values that

> Return value of the method is never used

---

Here is the actual code below, a builder class.

```
public static class StreamParserBuilder{
    //optional - have defaults:
    private long spanLimit1 = 2000L;
    private long spanLimit2 = 100000L;
    private long spanLimit3 = 3000000L;
    private String[] coordinates = {"L1", "R2"};
    private String outputDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    private boolean isLastSteam = false;

    //required from the builder.
    private String[] args;
    private String inputFile;
    private String streamData;
    private boolean isPaired;

    public StreamParserBuilder(String[] args, String inputFile, String streamData, boolean isPaired){
        this.args = args;
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
        this.streamData = streamData;
        this.isPaired = isPaired;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder withSpanLimit1(long spanLimit1){
        this.spanLimit1 = spanLimit1;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder withSpanLimit2(long spanLimit2){
        this.spanLimit2 = spanLimit2;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder withSpanLimit3(long spanLimit3){
        this.spanLimit3 = spanLimit3;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder withCoordinates(String[] coordinates){
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder withOutputDirectory(String outputDirectory){
        this.outputDirectory = outputDirectory;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParserBuilder isLastStream(boolean isLastSteam){
        this.isLastSteam = isLastSteam;
        return this;
    }

    public StreamParser build(){
        return new StreamParser(this);
    }
```

Is there an issue with the code, maybe i've instantiated the .build() method incorrectly? The code for my StreamParser constructor:

```
private StreamParser(StreamParserBuilder streamParserBuilder){
    this.args = streamParserBuilder.args;
    this.inputFile = streamParserBuilder.inputFile;
    this.streamData = streamParserBuilder.streamData;
    this.spanLimit1 = streamParserBuilder.spanLimit1;
    this.spanLimit2 = streamParserBuilder.spanLimit2;
    this.spanLimit3 = streamParserBuilder.spanLimit3;
    this.coordinates = streamParserBuilder.coordinates;
    this.outputDirectory = streamParserBuilder.outputDirectory;
    this.isLastStream = streamParserBuilder.isLastSteam;
    this.isPaired = streamParserBuilder.isPaired;
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this? If the code is okay, what causes this warning?

Edit: Usage of the StreamParserBuilder, calling the withX functions:

```
 StreamParserBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamParserBuilder(args, inputFile, stream, isPaired);
        if (isSpanOneReplaced) streamBuilder.withSpanLimit1(spanLimit1);
        if (isSpanTwoReplaced) streamBuilder.withSpanLimit2(spanLimit2);
        if (isSpanThreeReplaced) streamBuilder.withSpanLimit3(spanLimit3);
        if (areCoordinatesReplaced) streamBuilder.withCoordinates(coordinates);
        if (isOutputDirectoryReplaced) streamBuilder.withOutputDirectory(outputDirectory);
        if (streamCount == streamData.size()) streamBuilder.isLastStream(true);
        StreamParser streamParser = streamBuilder.build();
```

Comment: weird... how do you call your Builder? do you call the withX methods? What I usually do different is not passing the Builder as param to the constructor, but the fields, but that shouldn't have an impact on the issue you're having

Comment: Like so:  StreamParserBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamParserBuilder(args, inputFile, stream, isPaired).build(); I thought about adding the fields instead, but I didn't think it would make a difference.

Comment: Your code talks about warnings raised about use of `withX` method, but attached code doesn't show anything about how these methods are called. As you might think, the use of these methods is actually what's important, not the methods themselves.

Comment: @Sam you never call the withX methods, hence indeed, the return statements never run

Comment: That makes sense, I have posted extra code showing how I'm calling the StreamParserBuilder. I do indeed call the .withX method in the usual way.

Comment: have you verified those if statements evaluate in true?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"Return value of the method is never used" is a warning from the `Java | Declaration redundancy | Method can be void` inspection. This warning is generated because the value returned by this method is never used at the call site. It's possible to ignore the warning by annotating the class with `@SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")` or disabling the inspection in `Settings  | Editor | Inspections`.

Answer (score 3):

As I have found, Intellij IDEA gives this warning for `public` methods, which is questionable, because a `public` (or `protected`) method could be called from other packages that Intellij IDEA has not included in its analysis, and that is *the likely case* if you are writing a library (JAR) for use by other projects.

Fortunately, [configuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176128/545127) *Settings > Editor > Inspections* to disable the *Java > Declaration redundancy > Method can be void* inspection is **not** the only fix. That inspection can alternatively be configured with an option of *Maximal reported method visibility* changed from `Public` to `Package-private`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `with` methods of a builder `return this;` is so method calls can be chained:

```
StreamParserBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamParserBuilder(args, inputFile, stream, isPaired)
    .withSpanLimit1(spanLimit1)
    .withSpanLimit2(spanLimit2)
    .withSpanLimit3(spanLimit3);
```

In your case, you're ignoring the returned value in your calling code:

```
// returns StreamBuilderParses, which you're ignoring
if (isSpanOneReplaced) streamBuilder.withSpanLimit1(spanLimit1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't really benefit from the builder pattern. If it's rare use case, I'd just let it be, and ignore the warnings. But if it's frequent, it might be beneficial to include conditional assignment directly to your builder.
So you may write either:

```
streamBuilder.conditionallyWithSpanLimit1(isSpanOneReplaced, spanLimit1)
    .conditionallyWithSpanLimit2(isSpanTwoReplaced, spanLimit2)
    // etc.
```

That would mean to duplicate all builder methods.

Or you can introduce fluent preposition:

```
streamBuilder.when(isSpanOneReplaced).setSpanLimit1(spanLimit1)
```

Implementation of this would be extremely simple, if your builder is interface.

```
public interface Builder {
    Builder setSpanLimit1(int value);
    Builder when(boolean condition);
    Object build();
}
```

Your `when()` method can return a proxy bypasing following method call, if it's not `build()` and returning back the oeiginal builder.

Answer (score 0):

Better design would be if StreamParser doesn't know anything about its builder. I mean, constructor StreamParser doesn't take builder as parameter.
Better usage is:

```
StreamParserBuilder builder = new StreamParserBuilder(params)
                                    .withSpanLimit1(3)
                                    .withSpanLimit2(4);
StreamParser parser = builder.build();
// after that you can continue building object and create another parser
builder.withSpanLimit3(4);
StreamParser anotherParser = builder.build();
```