# Room query with ID returns null

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room Persistance Library for my database. One of my queries returns null and I don't understand why:

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item{

    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo (name = "I_ID")
    private final int iId;

    @ColumnInfo (name = "I_Name")
    private final String iName;

    public int getIId() {
        return iId;
    }

    public String getIName() {
        return iName;
    }

    public Item(int iId, String iName) {
        this.iId = iId;
        this.iName = iName;
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE I_ID = :iId")
    Item getItemById(int iId);
}
```

This Query shows a warning: `Return value of the method is never used`.
And it always returns null, even when I am sure that an item with the given ID exists in the database. Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176128/4390987

Comment: I see a problem with your code

Comment: try to get in List like below in my answer

Comment: Show where are you using _getItemById()_ method and how ??

Answer (score 0):

I found try to use like this :

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE I_ID = :iId")
List<Item> getItemById(int iId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be nothing wrong with the given code. Rather that you are not checking for the possible result that nothing was returned due to the id not being a id of an Item.

That is using the Item class as above, along with a slightly modified ItemDao (to allow inserts) as per :-

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE I_ID = :iId")
    Item getItemById(int iId);

    @Insert
    long insert(Item item); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED 
}
```

With an @Database of :-

```
@androidx.room.Database(version = 1,entities = {Item.class})
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ItemDao itemDao();
}
```

And the following code in an activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database mDB;
    ItemDao mItemDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB = Room.databaseBuilder(this,Database.class,"mydb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        mItemDao = mDB.itemDao();

        mItemDao.insert(new Item(1,"Item1"));
        mItemDao.insert(new Item(2,"Item2"));
        logItemInfo(mItemDao.getItemById(1));
        logItemInfo(mItemDao.getItemById(2));
    }

    private void logItemInfo(Item i) {
        Log.d("ITEMINFO","Item is " + i.getIName() + " ID is " + i.getIId());
    }
}
```

The resultant output in the log is :-

```
2019-10-02 07:36:41.180 D/ITEMINFO: Item is Item1 ID is 1
2019-10-02 07:36:41.181 D/ITEMINFO: Item is Item2 ID is 2
```

It appears that your issue is that you are likely passing an id to the select that is not actually an id in use.

For example using :-

```
    mItemDao.deleteAllItems(); //<<<<<<<<<<< Added to Item Dao as @Query("DELETE FROM Item") to make this rerunnable

    mItemDao.insert(new Item(1,"Item1")); //<<<<<<<<<< AS WAS
    mItemDao.insert(new Item(2,"Item2")); //<<<<<<<<<< AS WAS
    logItemInfo(mItemDao.getItemById(1)); //<<<<<<<<<< AS WAS
    logItemInfo(mItemDao.getItemById(2)); //<<<<<<<<<< AS WAS
    logItemInfo(mItemDao.getItemById(100)); //<<<<<<<<<< ATTEMPT TO GET AN INVALID ID
```

Results in a Null Pointer exception (when the attempt is made to access the Item in the logItemInfo method) as there is **no Item with an id of 100**, which is the likely cause of the issue you have described (i.e. you are requesting a non existant row).

Modifying the **logItemInfo** method to be :-

```
private void logItemInfo(Item i) {
    if (i == null) {
        Log.d("ITEMINFO","NOT AN ITEM");
        return;
    }
    Log.d("ITEMINFO","Item is " + i.getIName() + " ID is " + i.getIId());
}
```

The the resultant output (instead of an exception) is :-

```
2019-10-02 07:57:21.189 11388-11388/aso.asofkinroom D/ITEMINFO: Item is Item1 ID is 1
2019-10-02 07:57:21.190 11388-11388/aso.asofkinroom D/ITEMINFO: Item is Item2 ID is 2
2019-10-02 07:57:21.190 11388-11388/aso.asofkinroom D/ITEMINFO: NOT AN ITEM
```